# Take out Binary data column from SQL Server database to different store

Tags: sql-server, sqlbulkcopy, data-transfer

I'm looking for the best available options to take out binary data column from a SQL Server database to a different data store (S3, NetApp or any document DB)

We have a legacy table that stores gzipped XML file in a `varchar` column. Over the time, the table has grown a lot and now we have more than 9 billion records (8 TB in size) we are planning to take this out from the database, and store in a different type of storage.

What would be the best option to move this data set out?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. YOU have to make the decision about what is best. Sounds like you have several issues with the way you are dealing with data. You are storing a compressed file in a varchar column. Why are you zipping the xml in the first place? If you need to store XML use the XML datatype.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @SeanLange here some background of this problem.This a legacy system. I'm not sure even XML data type is available when they design this. What they have done is they have put a threshold value for file size.If it exceeds the threshold it will store in the file store otherwise store in a DB. When I analyze the historical data there is nothing much stored in the file system. all most all the the files are in the DB. Use case wise we don't need to quary the data in the XML file. We just need to store it and give it back. Challenge is moving this to a different store while  using this data in prod